# How would you spatially relate NetLogo turtles that are part of another turtle?

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, how would you spatially handle a situation such as people (a turtle breed) getting into a car (another turtle breed) and driving around? Would you keep them all on the same patch at all times; or send the people off to some holding patch and relate them with a pointer variable or a link? If you keep them on the same patch, which intuitively sounds like the best approach, would you trust that to be enough to know who is in each car (using the agentset people-here), or would you also use a pointer variable or link at the same time?

people-here should be good enough if the movement commands are nested properly:

```
ask cars[move ask people-here [move]]
```

but this sounds like it could be easily muddled. Then if you are using a link anyway, why bother with all the moving about commands?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally suggest to use links combined with [`tie`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tie) to solve this problem. `Tie`, combined with an undirected link makes it so that if one turtle moves or rotates, the other turtles moves or rotates together with it. It can also be used with directed links but that doesn't have any benefits for your question.

In the sample code down below I have the turtles move to a car, create a link with it and then tie themselves to it, after which the cars can drive them around. After you are done driving, you can simply tell the link to `untie` or to `die`

```
breed [cars car]
breed [humans human]

to setup
  
  ca
  
  set-default-shape cars "car"
  set-default-shape humans "person"
  
  create-cars 2 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set size 2
  ]
  
  create-humans 5 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  
end

to get-in
  
  ask humans [
    let my-car one-of cars
    move-to my-car
    create-link-with my-car [tie]
  ]
  
end

to move-cars
  
  ask cars [fd 1]
  
end

to get-out
  
  ask links [die]
  ask humans [fd 1]
  
end
```